Why the result is the same even if the variable isnt static?
char next_char(void){

   char letter='a';

    while(letter!='z'){
            letter=letter+1;
    char next_char(void);
    }
    printf("%c",letter);

}

When the variable letter is static , it has a specific location in the memory and its lifespan is the same with the programm so every time we initialize the variable letter it gets updated.But if its not static the lifespan of the varible letter is the same with the function so i cant find why doesnt this  programm  run endlessly and it returns each time the same result (z);

What do you think that char next_char(void); does? What are you expecting to happen? What does really happen? What is the expected output? What is the actual output? And please try to create a proper [mre] to show us.

It doesn't return a proper value because it is missing a return letter; statement. char next_char(void); is just a declaration. Were you intending to call the function recursively?

@Someprogrammerdude I wrote the function smarty i called it that way but i dont know why it works without using the static variable .I hope that you are able of unnderstanding that there is diffrence between understanding smt and expecting  to happe.So if you want to be polite and help thanks but dont talk  like that

@John - The programmer dude is using the "rubber duck"-method of debugging. Instead of us telling you what is wrong with the program, you should try to explain why it works, preferably by saying it out loud to your favorite toy (like the duck). Most often, when explaining, the result is "Wait, that doesn't work!", and then you don't have to ask anyone else.

This whole function is 100% equivalent to printf("z"); followed by undefined behavior and possibly a crash since there is no return statement.

char next_char(void); is a function prototype that does not call the function.
You need to call it: next_char(); and you will see the desired output https://godbolt.org/z/KhaTEndbP
PS I have modify your function as you do not return aything
